# Angular ng-click's inside a dynamically created d3 chart are not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create a d3 chart using an Angular directive. I manage to create it, but the problem is that I want some ng-click events on the chart elements and I'm not really sure how this should be done.

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('circleChart', function($parse, $window, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                datajson: '='
            },
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

                var circleChart = new CircleChart(scope.datajson);
                circleChart.initialise(scope);
                var svg = circleChart.generateGraph();
                svg = angular.element(svg);

                console.log(svg);
                //scope.$apply(function() {
                  var content = $compile(svg)(scope);
                  elem.append(content);
                //});
            }
        }
    });
```

The CircleChart object creates my d3 chart and there is the place I attach an ng-click attribute to the chart elements (doesn't seem to be a proper Angular way of doing it):

```
var CircleChart = Class.create({
    initialise: function(scope) {
        this.datajson = scope.datajson;
    },

    generateGraph: function() {

    .............

    var chartContent = d3.select("div#chart-content");

    var svg = chartContent.append("svg")
        .attr("id", "circle")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter)
        .style("border-radius", "50px")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

      ...............

           var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("class", function(d) {
                    return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
                })
                .attr("id", function(d) {
                    return d.id;
                })
                .attr("value", function(d) {
                    return d.name
                })
                .attr("parent", function(d) {
                    if (d.parent) return d.parent['id']
                })
                .attr("ng-click", function(d) {
                    return "getEgs('" + d.id + "')";
                })

    ...............
```

The d3 code is working fine because if I remove the compile code from the directive, the chart gets drawn, but the ng-clicks don't fire.

If I leave the compile code there, it goes into an infinite loop and the browser is building up memory until I have to kill it.

Obviously, my method is not working and it will be awesome if someone can help me out

Comment: What is the `svg` in the `generateGraph` function? Is that detached DOM? Also, in my opinion, it is not a good idea to generate angular templates from code. The way I would do it is by passing callbacks to `CircleChart` either during initialization or during invocation, capture the click event in d3 and invoke that callback via Javascript code.

Comment: @musically_ut I updated my question with the svg creation code. I'm trying to understand what you said about passing the callbacks. Are you referring to the actual function that I want to call with the ng-click? I can probably access that if I use the controller's scope in my directive.

Comment: Yes, I'd rather that you call the function `getEgs` inside `.on('click', ...)` instead of outputting an `ng-click` in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are modifying the DOM from inside the `CircleChart.generateGraph` and re-appending the contents of the element in you directive: `elem.append(content)` after compilation, you (probably) end up in an infinite loop.

If you do want to compile the template thus produced, you can simple call `$compile(elem.contents())(scope);` without having to `clear` and `append` the content again. `$compile` will work Angular magic on the DOM *in-place*.

---

However, as I suggested in the comments, since you have access to the whole scope in `CircleChart` (which in my opinion is probably an overkill), you should capture the click event in `d3` and invoke the `getErgs` function from code instead of `$compile`-ing the code and delegating the task to Angular.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to get it working now. What I did was to access my controller in the directive `controller: 'egCtrl'`, then instead of placing `getEgs()` on the controller's `$scope`, I add it as an attrribute like: `this.getEgs = function() {}`. Then as you said, I use d3's `on.('click', ...)`.