# ng-click not working in D3 generated svg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, angularjs-ng-click

I'm using D3 with Angular and I want to insert some text elements into my svg and have an `ng-click` on them to fire off some functions in my controller.  However it seems the `ng-click` never even fires.  I've tried using `$compile` as suggested in the following posts:

- [How do I use angularjs directives in generated d3 html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399336/how-do-i-use-angularjs-directives-in-generated-d3-html)
- [Angular ng-click's inside a dynamically created d3 chart are not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055166/angular-ng-clicks-inside-a-dynamically-created-d3-chart-are-not-working)

neither of those solutions work for me.  it does appear the `$compile` is doing something because it appends the attributes `role="button"` and `tabindex="0"` to my element like so:

**Before** `$compile`:

```
<svg>
   <text y="30" cursor="pointer" ng-click="alert('clicked')">CLICK ME</text>
</svg>
```

**After** `$compile`:

```
<svg>
   <text y="30" cursor="pointer" ng-click="alert('clicked')" role="button" tabindex="0">CLICK ME</text>
</svg>
```

I'm wondering if something on the page may be stealing the click event? it seems that angular has added a click handler the the root html element.  I have never noticed this before

[image]

This is the directive code I have

```
.directive('clickMe', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
      var svg = d3.select(element[0])
        .append('svg');
        svg.append('text')
          .text('CLICK ME')
          .attr('y', '30')
          .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
          .attr('ng-click', 'alert(\'clicked\')');

      var compiledSvg = $compile(svg.node())(scope);
      element[0].children[0].replaceWith(compiledSvg[0]);
})
```

A jsfiddle with the versions of D3 and Angular I'm using which illustrates the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/soultrip/604pts5v/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that `alert` is in scope inside your template. Instead, create a method in your directive scope and call that on `ngClick`.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
      let svg = d3.select(element[0])
        .append('svg');
      svg.append('text')
        .text('CLICK ME')
        .attr('y', '30')
        .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
        .attr('ng-click', 'showAlert(\'clicked\')');
      let compiledSvg = $compile(svg.node())(scope);
      element[0].children[0].replaceWith(compiledSvg[0]);

      scope.showAlert = function(message) {
        alert(message);
      };
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/604pts5v/5/

Comment: that works but I thought `alert()` would be globally available.  I guess I need to work on my angular skillz...

Comment: The only thing that is available to an angular template is what is explicitly placed in `$scope`.